# Cannot marshal a struct that contains a union

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling, unions

I have a C++ struct that looks like this:

```
struct unmanagedstruct
{
    int             flags;
    union
    {
        int             offset[6];
        struct
        {
            float           pos[3];
            float           q[4];
        } posedesc;
    } u;
};
```

And I'm trying to Marshal it like so in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public class managedstruct {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int flags;

    [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] offset;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct posedesc {
        [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public float[] pos;

        [FieldOffset(12), MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public float[] q;
    }

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public posedesc pose;
}
```

However, when I try loading data into my struct only the first 3 elements of the **offset** array are there (the array's length is 3). I can confirm that their values are correct - but I still need the other 3 elements. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

I'm using these functions to load the struct:

```
private static IntPtr addOffset(IntPtr baseAddress, int byteOffset) {
    switch (IntPtr.Size) {
        case 4:
            return new IntPtr(baseAddress.ToInt32() + byteOffset);
        case 8:
            return new IntPtr(baseAddress.ToInt64() + byteOffset);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static T loadStructData<T>(byte[] data, int byteOffset) {
    GCHandle pinnedData = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T output = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(addOffset(pinnedData.AddrOfPinnedObject(), byteOffset), typeof(T));
    pinnedData.Free();
    return output;
}
```

Loading example:

```
managedstruct mystruct = loadStructData<managedstruct>(buffer, 9000);
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How is the marshalling code supposed to know when to marshal the union as `int[]` or `float[]` ? Is it supposed to choose for each array element, or is it always one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this but I believe that the Union means that the same memory is used for both members. In the case of the C++ structure, an int[] or a posedesc structure. So the size of the structure will be sizeof(int) + sizeof(posedisc). Meaning, Union doesn't mean you'll have both an int[] and a posedisc you'll have shared memory that can be either of those types in C++ land but only one or the other in managed land.

So I think you probably need two managed structures, one that has offset and one that has posedisc. You can pick one or the other in your call to LoadStruct. Optionally you could create a byte[] field and have calculated properties that convert those bytes into the desired types.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for problem might be the fact that in C++, `int` has a size that depends on the architecture.

In other words, in some circumstances, your `offset` array in the C++ struct may be actually an array of 64 bit values.

Now, in your C# struct, whenever you used the `MarshalAs` attribute, you do not specify the `ArraySubType` parameter.

According to the documentation, when you omit `ArraySubType`, the struct is supposed to be marshalled according to the type of the managed array, but maybe the fact that the `offset` array in the C++ struct is not spread accros 48 bytes instead of 24, is causing the problem you encountered.

My suggestion would be to try to change all `int` to `long` in the C++ struct to ensure the size is always the same, and also add the `ArraySubType` parameter in all your `MarshalAs` attributes for arrays.

Comment: The size of `long` also depends on the architecture.  I suggest `int32_t` or any of the other fixed-size types from `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party, but my best guess is that your `offset` array gets overwritten by `pos` array when the marshaller reaches the field, and it will be the **reference** that gets overwritten, not the actual elements. Therefore, `offset` will always be of length 3 (and try `GetType` on it, it should return `Single[]`. This is what you get for overlapped references.).

So either you can delete `q` and set `pos`' size to 7, or you can use `fixed` arrays (although I'm not sure how it will get marshalled).